# Formatting Rabl for Ember or Mapping Ember to Rabl?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, ember-data, rabl

My rails app used to produce JSON that looked like this:

```
{"paintings":
  [
    {"id":1,"name":"a"},
    {"id":2,"name":"b"}
  ]
}
```

I added rabl json formatting, and now the json looks like this:

```
[
  {"id":1,"name":"a"},
  {"id":2,"name":"b"}
]
```

Ember is telling me

```
Uncaught Error: assertion failed: Your server returned a hash with the key 0 but you have no mapping for it
```

How can I make Ember understand this? Or how should I make rabl understandable to ember?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extend `DS.RESTSerializer` and change `extract` and `extractMany`. The following is merely a copy and paste from the serializer I use in .NET, for the same scenario:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();
var adapter = DS.RESTAdapter.create();
var serializer = Ember.get( adapter, 'serializer' );
serializer.reopen({
    extractMany: function (loader, json, type, records) {
        var root = this.rootForType(type);
        root = this.pluralize(root);
        var objects;

        if (json instanceof Array) {
            objects = json;
        }
        else {
            this.sideload(loader, type, json, root);
            this.extractMeta(loader, type, json);
            objects = json[root];
        }

        if (objects) {
            var references = [];
            if (records) { records = records.toArray(); }

            for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
                if (records) { loader.updateId(records[i], objects[i]); }
                var reference = this.extractRecordRepresentation(loader, type, objects[i]);
                references.push(reference);
            }

            loader.populateArray(references);
        }
    },
    extract: function (loader, json, type, record) {
        if (record) loader.updateId(record, json);
        this.extractRecordRepresentation(loader, type, json);
    }
});
```

And before you set your store, you must configure your model to sideload properly:

```
serializer.configure( 'App.Painting', {
    sideloadAs: 'paintings'
} );

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    adapter: adapter,
    revision: 12
});
```

Now you should be able to load rootless JSON payload into your app.

(see [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/schawaska/6gCKm/))

Comment: Thank you this was the answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Found a solution.  My index.json.rabl looked like this:

```
collection @paintings 
extends 'paintings/show'
```

Now it looks like this:

```
collection @paintings => :paintings
extends 'paintings/show'
```

Comment: this might actually be better, so you don't have to extend the serializer

Comment: in this case yes but I was also trying to better understand the serializer